# como mostrar un formulario al cerrar el anterior en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

cómo puedo volver a mostrar un formulario determinado al cerrar el anterior? tengo un panel en mi menú principal en dónde muestro los formularios que se abren, ahora, cómo puedo mostrar el dashboard cada vez que se cierra un formulario? este es el método mostrar formularios que estoy implementando. el código está hecho en C#

```
    //METODO MOSTRAR DASHBOARD
    private void MostrarDashboard(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormEnPanel(new FrmDashboard());
    }

    private Form activeForm = null;
    //METODO PARA ABRIR FORM DENTRO DE PANEL
    private void AbrirFormEnPanel(Form formHijo)
    {
        if (activeForm != null) activeForm.Close();
        activeForm = formHijo;
        formHijo.TopLevel = false;
        formHijo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        formHijo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        PnContenedor.Controls.Add(formHijo);
        PnContenedor.Tag = formHijo;
        formHijo.Show();
        formHijo.BringToFront();
        formHijo.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MostrarDashboard);
    }
```

sobre cargué el método con el evento FormClosed pero genera un error. si por favor puedan ayudarme :)

Comment: ¿Y cual es el error que genera?.

Comment: Creo que si quieres abrir un form hijo puedes hacerlo con ShowDialog()